# Excel Formula for Max

Tags: excel, max

I am using the following function in Excel but it keeps giving me errors. **Is there something wrong with the use of Max function?**

Cells E2, D2 and E2 all contain numerical values.

My aim is to take the difference of D2- E2 when D2 > E2, else take 0.

```
=-E6*(52 -MAX ((D2 - E2),0))
```

Comment: What errors are you seeing?

Comment: You are right. When I removed the parenthesis around D2 - E2 it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only error that Excel 2010 reports for me with this expression is that it does not like the spaces in the formula. If I remove the spaces, this formula works as intended.

Answer (score 1):

Just get rid of the space between `MAX` and `(`.  The following works fine for me.

```
=-E6*(52 -MAX((D2 - E2),0))
```